# Setting parameter controls and using filters

Tags: filter, parameters, dataset, controls, tableau-api

I currently have a dataset of speeding fines in NSW.
I've created a bar chart that displays the top 10 frequencies of speeding offenses. These offenses are split up between school zone offenses and normal speeding offenses.

[image: http://puu.sh/GdSXB/2f7ee2e635.png]

I'm trying to set a parameter control where the end-user can toggle showing the top 10 normal speeding offenses (pink), top 10 school zone offenses (purple) or both together (pink and purple).

I've gotten the below parameter control:
[image: http://puu.sh/GdSXV/770c962ac3.png]

However nothing happens to the bar-chart.

My Dataset looks like the following:
[image: http://puu.sh/GdSXf/a5b5a3297b.png]

I have a School Zone Indicator boolean that is a Y if the speeding offense occurred during school zone time.

Can someone help me figure out in filtering this out when setting parameter controls?

Comment: Any reason you use a parameter? Doesn't it work with a filter on your SCHOOL_ZON_IND field? It sounds like that's what you're effectively trying to do, filter for Y, blank or both

Comment: I'm submitting this visualization for an application for a job. I've submitted a my viz and i've received feedback on it to use parameter control which is what i'm trying to do for my 2nd draft.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll give a solution below but worth asking the person providing the feedback why they prefer a parameter. Only reason I can think is for the option to say "Show Both" instead of "All".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on this article showing [how to add all to a parameter in Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-add-an-all-to-a-parameter/).

We need to create a parameter with the same values as the field. As your field is either Y or Null let's create a new field to convert the Null to N. Call it isSchool with the formula:

```
IFNULL([SCHOOL_ZONE_IND],"N")
```

Create a parameter based on that field with the values Y, N and All. Display As whatever you want, so you can display parameter value All as Show Both if you wish.

Put [isSchool] to filters.

In the filter you want to filter Condition - by Formula. Enter this formula:

```
IFNULL([isSchool],"1")=IF [YourParam]!="All" THEN [YourParam] ELSE IFNULL([isSchool],"1") END
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it! I follow the steps that were outlined, I created a Calculated Field called isSchool and a Parameter called isSchoolParameter. Unfortunately, the School Zone offenses are not appearing. The Normal speeding offences are appearing.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the code like this: IFNULL([SCHOOL_ZONE_IND],"N") = 
IF [isSchoolParameter] = "N" 
THEN [isSchoolParameter]
ELSE IFNULL([SCHOOL_ZONE_IND], "Y") 
END I can switch between School Zone Speeding and Normal Speeding Offence but I can't seem to figure out how to code the All.

Comment: Yes, you have tried to merge the 2 steps. First create the field isSchool. Then create your parameter containing the same values as isSchool - i.e. All, Y, N. Then add the formula I provided into the Condition area of the isSchool filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to setup the Parameter Control based on your code. Can I ask, as i'm not familiar with the language that Tableau uses, where can I go to learn more about the syntax behind the Tableau language?

Comment: Tableau doesn't have a language. It has a few built in functions, like Excel, but that's it. No way to code anything and no way to create your own functions.